# java - Generating permutations using Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to write a recursive program that can print all permutations of a list of integers taken from a file, I am using HashMap to store list, where the keys are the numbers and the values are the number of times the key occurs in the list. The code is given below:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class perm
{
    public static void permute(HashMap<Integer, Integer> map)
    {
        if(map.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println();
        }
        else
        {
            Set<Integer> keys = map.keySet();
            for(int num: keys)
            {
                System.out.print(Integer.toString(num)+",");
                int val = map.get(num) -1;
                if(val == 0)
                {
                    map.remove(num);   
                }
                else
                {
                    map.put(num, val);
                }
                permute(map);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args []) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        HashMap <Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
        int num;
        while(in.hasNextInt())
        {
            num = in.nextInt();
            if(map.containsKey(num))
            {
                map.put(num, map.get(num)+1);
            }
            else
            {
                map.put(num,1);
            }
        }
        permute(map);
    }
}
```

I am getting a concurrency error, but I don't understand why, the error is given below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1429)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1453)
    at perm.permute(perm.java:15)
    at perm.permute(perm.java:27)
    at perm.permute(perm.java:27)
    at perm.permute(perm.java:27)
    at perm.main(perm.java:48)
```

--------------------Code Edited based on comments --------------------

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class perm
{
    public static void permute(HashMap<Integer, Integer> map)
    {
        if(map.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println();
        }
        else
        {
            Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator(); 
            //Set<Integer> keys = map.keySet();
            while(it.hasNext())
            //for(int num: keys)
            {
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                int num = (int) pair.getKey();
                System.out.print(Integer.toString(num)+",");
                int val = (int) pair.getValue()-1;
                //HashMap<Integer, Integer> newMap = map;
                //int val = map.get(num) -1;
                if(val == 0)
                {
                    //newMap.remove(num);
                    it.remove(); 
                }
                else
                {
                    //newMap.put(num, val);
                    pair.setValue(val);
                }
                permute(map);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args []) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        HashMap <Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
        int num;
        while(in.hasNextInt())
        {
            num = in.nextInt();
            if(map.containsKey(num))
            {
                map.put(num, map.get(num)+1);
            }
            else
            {
                map.put(num,1);
            }
        }
        permute(map);
    }
}
```

The same error still persists. I then went back to the initial approach and stored a temporary copy of the HashMap I was trying to iterate over and modified only the temporary copy and not the original one, the same error persists.

---- Code edit based on Answer 1 ------

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class perm
{
    public static void permute(HashMap<Integer, Integer> map)
    {
        if(map.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println();
        }
        else
        {
            //Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator(); 
            HashMap<Integer, Integer> newMap = map;
            Set<Integer> keys = map.keySet();
            //while(it.hasNext())
            for(int num: keys)
            {
                //Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                //int num = (int) pair.getKey();
                System.out.print(Integer.toString(num)+",");
                //int val = (int) pair.getValue()-1;
                //HashMap<Integer, Integer> newMap = map;
                int val = map.get(num) -1;
                if(val == 0)
                {
                    newMap.remove(num);
                    //it.remove(); 
                }
                else
                {
                    newMap.put(num, val);
                    //pair.setValue(val);
                }
                permute(newMap);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args []) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        HashMap <Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
        int num;
        while(in.hasNextInt())
        {
            num = in.nextInt();
            if(map.containsKey(num))
            {
                map.put(num, map.get(num)+1);
            }
            else
            {
                map.put(num,1);
            }
        }
        permute(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the suggestion in the above thread but still getting the same error.

Comment: Please post your updated code. If you were using the suggestion of this thread correctly, you would not get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: Code added after ---Edit line---

Comment: the `remove()` statement on `it` is fine. Problem is the call to `pair.setValue(...)`. You cannot add elements to a map while iterating over this map in this form. General approach is to create a new, temporary map and merge those map after the iteration.

Comment: Comment on last edit: `newMap` and `map` are the same object.  The same problems apply.  Can you batch your inserts/deletes and apply them after you've finished iterating?

Comment: I guess not since its a recursive call. I will have to go with some other direction. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

`java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown when you modify a collection that you are iterating over.  In your case you are both iterating over and modifying the `HashMap` in your `permute` method.

If this exception was not thrown then you would end up with strange and seemingly random results each time your program ran depending on the generated `hashCode` of the integer being added or removed from the map.

Comment: To elaborate a bit more, disallowing concurrent modification enforces iteration dependability, as when you iterate over a collection you know it will not change in length or content. You can create another object that is a copy of the key List and iterate over that or keep a record of all the insertions you want to make and then make them all at once after the iteration.

Comment: In the above program I am iterating over a Set of keys, which is a separate collection from the HashMap. 
I am iterating over the Set and modifying the HashMap, they are two different collections, so I don't understand why it is giving this error.

Comment: When you add or remove entries in a HashMap you are also modifying the keys of that HashMap (the collection you are iterating over).

Answer (score 0):

you are getting ConcurrentModificationException because you are trying to modify map while iterating. Good link to understand it
http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/02/fail-safe-vs-fail-fast-iterator-in-java.html